# I want create multiple image image field in category in magento for slider?

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I want to show individual category slider in category through multiple image field from back-end.
How can create extra image field in category and how can display in front end. 
if we are using installer for this so how can run installer for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is your effort?

Comment: I have used  code for add i image field and run this code on head.phtml file but didn't created field in category.

Answer (score -1):

```
Step #1 
create a file name it sliderimg.php

Step #2 add below code to sliderimg.php

<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup;
$attribute  = array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'label'=> 'Slider image 1',
    'input' => 'image',
    'backend'       => 'catalog/category_attribute_backend_image',
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'default' => "",
    'group' => "Slider" 
);

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'slider_img1', $attribute);
$installer->endSetup();
?>

Step # 3 Save file to your Magento root installation
Step # 4 run your "sliderimg.php" through your url www.yoursiet.com/sliderimg.php
go to admin>catalog>manage categories> you will see a new tab with image field.


#step # 5 add your slider image 
Note you can add multiple category attribute with the above script


Step # 6 

To call it in the front end. 
create a new file slider.phtml
add this code to "sldier.phtml"

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flickity/2.0.5/flickity.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!------ CSS ---------->





<style class="cp-pen-styles">

.slide--parent {
    max-width: 1400px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
p {
    line-height: 1.8;
}
h1 {
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    color: #343434;
    margin: 0;
}

small {
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #999;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 3em;
}
    small:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        left: -0em;
        top: 50%;
        height: 4px;
        width: 2.4em;
        background: red;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }


.parent--el {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
}
    .two--col {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }


figure {
    margin: 0;
}

.is-item {
    width: 60%;
}

enter code here
    .has--img {
        width: 40%;
    }


    .the-img {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
.the-img    img {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .is-item--inner {
    padding: 0em 3em;
}

hr {
    margin: 0.5em 0em;
    height: 4px;
    background: #eee;
    border: none;
}



</style>

<?php
$category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
$categories = $category->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('acc_img1'))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
        ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())
        ->addAttributeToSort('position', ASC);
?>

<div class="slide--parent">
    <?php foreach ($category as $child): ?>
    <div class="parent--el">
        <div class="two--col"> 
            <div class="is-item has--img">
                <figure class="the-img">
                    <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'catalog' . '/' . 'category' . '/' . $category->getSlider_img1() ?>">
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="is-item has--content">
                <div class="is-item--inner">
                    <h1><span><?php echo Mage::registry('current_category')->getAcc_title1() ?></span></h1>
                    <small>OPTIONAL ACCESSORIES</small>
                    <p><?php echo $category->getAcc_desc1() ?></p>
                <div class="msrp" style="color:#000;">MSRP <span class="msrp-price"><?php echo Mage::registry('current_category')->getAcc_msrp1() ?></span> <span style="color:#000;">usd</span></div>
                <br>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn1 menu-btn-brp-default" onclick="window.open('#' + location.search )">VIEW NOW &nbsp; <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>





<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flickity/2.0.5/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script> 
<script>
var slideEl = $(".slide--parent");

slideEl.flickity({
    imagesLoaded: true,
    wrapAround: true,
    autoPlay: 6000,
    pauseAutoPlayOnHover: false
});
</script>

call you block by CMS 
{{block type="core/template" template="home/slide.phtml"}}
note if you don't have the folder "home" create one!

NOTE: I used flickity Slider 

That's it guys 
hope you like it
```